Nginx not reading assets and HTML files from subdirectories properly
The directory for my webpage is something like this:
/var/www/domain.com/
|
|--css/
|  |
|  |--style.css
|
|--pages/
|  |
|  |--index.html
|  |--page-1.html
|  |--page-2.html
|
|--scripts/
|  |
|  |--script.js
|
|--images/
|  |
|  |--favicon.ico

In my html files, the assets are referenced with ../css/style.css, ../images/favicon.ico, and ../scripts/script.js. Similar, the additional html files are referenced as ./page-1.html and ./page-2.html. I was wondering how I would configure this setup in my Nginx conf files. I tried doing something like:
root /var/www/domain.com/;
index pages/index.html;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

Here, the CSS and JS appear to work as intended, however any page redirects to 404 and the favicon does not load at all. Will such a configuration work in this way? What would I need to achieve this? If not, how could I rearrange my folder directory/change my conf file so it loads everything properly?
Edit
I figured it out! Using this fixed it:
location / {
    root /var/www/domain.com/pages/;
    index index.html;
}
location ~*\.(js|css|ico)$ {
    root /var/www/domain.com/;
}


Please post your edit as an answer and then come back in a few days to accept the answer. Thanks.
